# No Source Code is available for type : GWT Compilation Error

Tags: java, json, gwt, httpresponse, http-get

I am trying to make get requests by a servlet in my GWT application. On compiling the code I am getting these errors.

```
[ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type org.apache.http.ParseException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type org.json.simple.parser.ParseException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

What should I do to remove these errors? 
Are these classes are not supported by GWT?

Following is the code I am using

```
public String getJSON() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, ParseException{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String url = "some - url - can't disclose";
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    JSONObject json_data = (JSONObject)parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    JSONArray results = (JSONArray)json_data.get("result");
}
```

This code is working fine If I use this on a usual java project/ console application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java code running in GWT is translated to Javascript, so some classes that work on a JVM won't work with GWT. The HttpClient and related classes are written to work on a JVM with full support for opening sockets, something that isn't allowed in a web browser, so these classes cannot be used.

To open a connection to the server you are using (subject to the browser Same Origin Policy), consider the RequestBuilder class, which allows you to provide a url and an HTTP method, and optionally headers, parameters, data, etc. This class is an abstraction over the XmlHttpRequest object in JavaScript, commonly used for AJAX requests in plain JS.

Answer (score 13):

If you use Maven then you can do this.

[maven-gwt-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) with parameter [compileSourcesArtifacts](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compileSourcesArtifacts) will do all sources management work and will let you to compile GWT module.

In the module that you want to include, you'll have to [enable the generation of source package](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html). And take a look at [external GWT module example on Github](https://github.com/slavikdobro/bilionix-core).

GWT can't compile any Java class to JavaScript client code. It supports only several base classes. See [GWT JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation).

Example pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ... -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <!-- ... -->
                <configuration>
                    <compileSourcesArtifacts>
                        <compileSourcesArtifact>com.my.group:my-artifact</compileSourcesArtifact>
                    </compileSourcesArtifacts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to inherit in your **.gwt.xml* needed module(s).

Like: `<inherits name="module_name"/>`

Answer (score 3):

You may not use classes that are not emulated by GWT in client side code unless you provide source code (impossible in your case as you are trying to use a 3rd party library).

List of all emulated JRE classes: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Read this comprehensive documentation on making cross-site requests in GWT: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html

Answer (score 1):

Your client source code may refer to a server source code. Just try to place your server source code in a shared package.

Answer (score 0):

When I get "no source code is available..." in a dialog in Chrome while loading a GWT app, along with the above answers I found 2 other causes:

1. It means that my server code refers to code which isn’t in the shared or server packages. (The compiler doesn't complain, but GWT does. Unfortunately the error message is NOT helpful.)
2. I forgot to supply a parameterless constructor for a class I am passing from client to server. (I.e. I wrote my own constructor WITH a parameter, so there is no default constructor.) GWT-RPC is serializing this class in the background and deserialization requires a parameterless constructor. So that's the problem, and again, the error message is unhelpful and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was caused by the fact that RemoteService interfaces were not included in the "Client" package only in the project package.